# ExperimentalCoroutinesApi Optin ? Android studio-kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

what is this?
what can i do to fix this.

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
Opt-in requirement marker annotation on override requires the same marker on base declaration

Comment: Move the annotation inside the function to right before the function call on the experimental function.

Answer (score 1):

Add it on top of your class declaration, so you do not need to add all over again:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class testClass {

    @Test
    fun testSomething() { }
```